# Confluent Kafka Rest Proxy authorization

Tags: authorization, apache-kafka

I am looking for ways to authorize each individual client request made through the rest proxy. Is there a mechanism to integrate the proxy with existing Kafka ACL's?

I already configured the HTTPS authentication with client certificates so I have a unique client token I can include with every request for authorization purpose. My preferred approach would be to introduce a custom servlet filter that integrates with Kafka ACL system using something like SimpleAclAuthorizer. Unfortunately, the Rest Proxy is not a standard Web application but runs the embedded Jetty, so configuration is a bit more convoluted.

My question is, what is the least intrusive way to to accomplish this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a single kafka client credentials for the REST Proxy to use when connecting to Kafka, but today you cannot pass through the credentials of each HTTP(s) client separately.  That feature is being worked on and will likely come out in a future release.

Comment: Do you mean basic authentication with username and password? Could you link to some documentation?

Comment: are you asking about the authentication from the HTTPS client and the Confluent REST Proxy or the Kafka client embedded in the Confluent REST Proxy and the Apache Kafka Brokers?

Comment: Just like the original poster I am asking about authentication of the client that talks to the REST proxy. The idea is that only authenticated clients can send data to Kafka.

Comment: Confluent has added security extensions (in the Enterprise version) to map HTTP authentication into Kafka with ACLs. Details are here https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/security.html and here https://docs.confluent.io/current/confluent-security-plugins/kafka-rest/introduction.html#confluentsecurityplugins-kafaka-rest-security-plugin

Answer (score 0):

RBAC is available now in Confluent Kafka but it is still in preview [here is the link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/confluent-security-plugins/kafka-rest/rbac-rest-proxy-security.html)